# Не записывается куки

Tags: php, cookie

Если я в адресную строку вбиваю партнерскую ссылку `http://one-love.by/?ref=3` и нажимаю `Enter`, попадаю на сайт, но в куки не записывается `GET['ref']`, если еще раз нажму `Enter` в адресной строке, то уже записывается в куки.
Вот сайт: `http://one-love.by`
+ как сделать чтобы куки записывался глобально на весь сайт, если я перейду http://one-love.by/katalog/platya?ref=3 то он не будет доступен на главных страницах, а только на страницах со вложенным урл 
Код:

```
  if (isset($_GET['ref'])){
        if (isset($_COOKIE['refer'])){
            echo "Реферал существует: " . $_COOKIE["refer"];
        }else {
         setcookie('refer', $_GET['ref'], time() + 60);  
         echo "Реферал новый: " . $_COOKIE["refer"];
        }
    }{
        echo "Реферал, если нет get: " . $_COOKIE["refer"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прям следующий аргумент в функции.

```
setcookie('refer', $_GET['ref'], time() + 60, '/');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Comment: а сколько нужно времени чтобы записалось в куки, просто пока не обновишь страницу он не выводит содержимое куки

Comment: Цитирую документацию: "После передачи клиенту cookie станут доступны через массив $_COOKIE при следующей загрузке страницы. Значения cookie также есть в $_REQUEST."
Так что кладете в куки, читаете при следующем реквесте.